# Caching ActiveDataProvider with redis

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How i cache data of active data provider query. If query run its get data from cache

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Aircraft::find()->andWhere(['owner_id' => 6, 'owner_type' => 'organization']),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`cache()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#cache()-detail) should be enough (as long as you have configured `cache` component):

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Aircraft::find()
        ->andWhere(['owner_id' => 6, 'owner_type' => 'organization'])
        ->cache($cacheDuration),
]);
```